# Desinstalar pod de Cocoapods en XCode

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, pods

Recientemente agregué a mi proyecto con swift en Xcode 9.3.1 un podfile con las referencias para poder utilizar el framework de google maps

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
   target 'MyApp' do
   pod 'GoogleMaps'
   pod 'GooglePlaces'
end
```

Me funcionó pero finalmente decidimos utilizar el MapKit y ya no me interesa conservar las librerías de google.

¿Cual es la mejor manera de eliminar todas las referencias que se agregaron a mi proyecto cuando ejecuté el podfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo quita el pod  (pod 'GooglePlaces') del podfile, y ejecuta el comando pod install desde la terminal

o si desdeas instalar dos gemas más para hacer una limpieza mas profunda:

```
1- $ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate
2- $ sudo gem install cocoapods-clean

3- $ pod deintegrate
4- $ pod clean
5- $ pod install
```